# Can I use banshee from the command line?

Tags: command-line, banshee

I love Banshee media player in general, and I already have an important library of music, which I've spent a lot of time organizing (labeling, correcting, etc).

I also use the command line a lot, so I wonder if there is a way I can control banshee from the command line. As in:

- Next, Prev, Stop, Play, etc
- In anyway query the Banshee database as if using the search box in the GUI

I was akin to program it myself if there isn't, but that would be another question :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to `man banshee`, it is possible to control playback. I'm not sure about searching though.

Here are a few of the controls that you mentioned. Check the `man` page for many more.

```
--next 
    Play the next track, optionally restarting if the 'restart' value is set

--previous 
    Play the previous track, optionally restarting if the 'restart value is set

--stop 
    Completely stop playback

--play 
    Start playback
```

Comment: Doh!, I guess need to RTFM!, thanks for pointing that out.

There are plenty of options but looks like I can't query the database. the query-* commands are just for printing information on the stdout. :-/

Comment: Yeah, looks like the query arguments are only for getting info about the current track. Not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: BTW, If this answer actually answers your question, please hit the checkmark beside it.

Comment: banshee stores in a SQLite database. From there you could do queries.

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/bin/banshee --next
/usr/bin/banshee --previous
/usr/bin/banshee --stop
/usr/bin/banshee --play
```

All those above can be used in XFCE for shortcuts on your keyboard, respectively for:

```
X86AudioNext
X86AudioPrev
X86AudioStop
X86AudioPlay
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to program an interface for Banshee (Other than just having the ability to send `banshee --next` or other control flag. Then you may be interested in the [MPD - The Music Player Daemon](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) which allows you to create your own interface or modify/use one of these [Clients](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients) designed to work over MPD

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a bit of commands you can use with banshee, it's been a ling time now, but here's a script I wrote because I could not find a way to play a smart playlist at login.
It was months ago, it was one of my first scripts and I did it for fun so it's pretty bad, I haven't tried it since but this should at least give you an example of how usable is banshee on the terminal :

```
   #!/bin/bash
    banshee --hide &
    sleep 3;
    banshee --play;

    while true; do
        pos=`banshee --query-position| sed s/position:\ //| sed s/,.*//`;
        dur=`banshee --query-duration| sed s/duration:\ //| sed s/,.*//`;
        left="$(expr $dur - $pos)";

        rating=`banshee --query-rating|sed s/rating:\ //`;
        isHumour="$(banshee --query-uri|sed s/.*Music//|grep /Humour)";

      if [[ $pos -lt "3" ]] && ([[ $rating -lt "2" ]] || [[ -n "$isHumour" ]]);
      then
        echo "next";
        exec banshee --next &
      else
        echo "sleep for" $left;
        sleep "$left";
        pos=`banshee --query-position| sed s/position:\ //| sed s/,.*//`;
        dur=`banshee --query-duration| sed s/duration:\ //| sed s/,.*//`;
        left= expr $dur - $pos;
        echo $left;
    fi;
    sleep 0.0001;
    done;
    exit 0;
```

Hope it helps, sorry if it confuses you...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a command-line interface to Banshee at this point. And I haven't heard anything to indicate that they would be working on one.

Comment: I think tutuca is just looking for a way to control Banshee from the command line; not a full-out command line interface (though that would be very cool).

Answer (score -1):

Here is what everyone has been looking for:

```
sh -c "sleep 1m; banshee --hide & sleep 20; banshee --play"
```

the `1m` stands for a timeout which you can change.

You need to put it in your start up applications

Comment: Can you explain how this allows what the OP was asking? Next, Prev, Stop, Play, Search database?