# Opening a track with Banshee

Tags: command-line, banshee

How can I open a track with Banshee using command line? Obviously `banshee file.mp3` don't work. Is there another command?

See what I'm trying to accomplish is to make puddletag to play tracks in banshee. There's a preference "Programs to play files with" in puddletag. I've tried `muinshee --stop && muinshee --play`. That should run as `muinshee --stop && muinshee --play <file>` from puddletag. But this just stops and plays the currently playing track. Not the file mentioned in the command.

Comment: Try reading the man page

Comment: @Radu sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think that this question is duplicate of [Can I use banshee from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1500/can-i-use-banshee-from-the-command-line). That question is about that **if Banshee can be controled from the command line* and this question is about **how to open a track with Banshee using command line**. I think that [Binoy Babu](http://askubuntu.com/users/20629/binoy-babu) knew about the fact that Banshee can be controled from the command line.

Comment: @demure of course i've read the man page. Try reading the question again. Radu Thanks

Comment: @BinoyBabu I just edited my answer for your new request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `man banshee`, you can use:

```
banshee --play file.mp3
```

or

```
 muinshee --play file.mp3
```

If you already play a track, use below command to change to another track:

```
banshee --play-enqueued another_file.mp3
```

More about: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/banshee.1.html

Comment: I'm aware of that. This opens banshee and plays the track. But repeating the command won't work if track if banshee is still running.

Comment: @BinoyBabu Did you tried `banshee --stop && banshee --play file.mp3`?

Comment: Sadly that just stops and play the 1st track instead of the 2nd one. Is that the expected behavior? Updated question.

Comment: What version are you using? Did you try running the command while you are already playing a track?

Comment: @BinoyBabu I use Banshee 2.6.1 and yes, I run the command while already playing a track. And now I found, is better to use `banshee --play-enqueued file.mp3` - I told you to see more on the `man` page :)